# React: Make padding into a component

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am coding a website in React using Semantic UI and am tired of writing the following again and again.

```
<Grid.Row style={{ marginBottom: "4em" }}>
```

There are multiple drawbacks of this approach:

- No standard way for me to maintain standard margin/ padding bottom or top values for the different spacings I put on different pages.
- writing style={{marginBottom:"4em"}} etc. again and again.

I want to convert this to a design token - encode these margin padding values with enums  (S \ M \ L \ XL) as a component. It would be ideal to expose them inside Semantic components itself something like :

```
<Grid.Row paddingBottom='S'>
```

OR

```
<Grid.Row childrenPadding='S'>
```

But I know this isn't possible since the <Grid.Row> is Semantic UI's component, not mine. What is the best approach I can take to encode these 'tokens'? I don't know what to search for in a search engine for this either :(

Comment: you can simply create a CSS class and place everywhere you need to style similarly. and also it is possible to create CSS as a JSON object and refer it when necessory.

Comment: I suggest you using [styled-component](https://styled-components.com/) as a good developer.

Answer (score 2):

One of great powers of `ReactJS` is that you can create your own customized components. You can easily create a component called for example `GridRow` which recives 2 props.

- children
- childrenPadding

Your component should return something like this:

```
<Grid.Row style={{padding:getPadding()}}>
 {children}
<Grid.Row>
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
 <GridRow childrenPadding="S">
     ... //Your childrens
  <Grid.Row>
```

`getPadding` could be a function returning desired value by switch case for example.
If you're using **Typescript** you can use enums. But in a JS way you can do this:

```
const getPadding = () => {
    switch(props.childrenPadding):
        case 'S': return '10px';
        case 'M': return '15px';
        ... // Other choices
}
```

Please be aware that this function's job is to return the padding value. You can do this by `if else` either.

Comment: Interesting approach! Could you elaborate more on the getPadding function bit? How to implement the values that will go into the getPadding? through enums?

Comment: @harshikerfuffle I've just edited my answer and added an example and more explanation for `getPadding`.

Answer (score 1):

Taking inspiration of material ui `Box`, you can create a wrapper which will accept a `component` prop to mount (which will be `Grid.Row` in your case). You can pass a token mapping inside (I have specified a sample padding mapping for reference)

```
const BoxWrapper = <K extends {}>({
  component: Component,
  children,
  props,
  ...style
}: React.CSSProperties & {
  component: React.ComponentType<K>;
  props: K;
  children: React.ReactChild;
}) => {
  const tokenToValueMapping = {
    s: '8px',
    m: '16px',
    l: '32px',
    xl: '64px',
  };
  if (style.padding in tokenToValueMapping)
    style.padding = tokenToValueMapping[style.padding];
  return (
    <Component style={style} {...props}>
      {children}
    </Component>
  );
};
```

You can than use it to mount your components:

```
<BoxWrapper component='div' padding='l'>Hello World</BoxWrapper>
```